# Programatically check if values match predefined rules in c#

Tags: c#, compare, logical-operators

I have stored a list of rules using Condition class as explained below. My goal is to check these rules against real values.

For example

```
public class Condition
{
public string Field {get;set;}
public string Operation {get;set;}
public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

for example

```
new Condition("order_status", "is", "confirmed")
```

How can i check if the property Status of Order instance actually matches provided condition?

```
public class Order
{
public string Status {get;set;}
}
```

I would love to provide you what I have tried, but I really dont have a solid idea how to get started on this one.

```
public class OrderConditionComparator
{
public void Compare(Order order, Condition condition)
{
    ...
}
```

}

Comment: You're going to have to do a whole lot of branching. First you'll have to figure out how to get the value of `Field`. Then you can `switch` on the `Operation` and use the corresponding logic to check the value of `Field` against `Value`. You could also try using [LINQ expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.8) for this if they fit your scenario.

Comment: I have found this article https://mobiusstraits.com/2015/08/12/expression-trees/

Comment: I would favor some Enum rather than strings.  Failing that, perhaps some sort of vocabulary that can be parsed (which doesnt rule out a role fpor enums)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure this is not the most elegant way of doing it, but you could use a `List<Func<Order, bool>>` which would be your ruleset, add rules to the list and for each order, loop through the ruleset and test if it passes all rules. Here's a sample:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        var orders = new List<Order>();
        var ruleset1 = new List<Func<Order, bool>>();
        var ruleset2 = new List<Func<Order, bool>>();

        AddRules(ruleset1);
        AddRules2(ruleset2);
        AddOrders(orders);

        foreach (var order in orders) {
            bool passed = true;
            foreach (var rule in ruleset1) {
                if (!(rule.Invoke(order))) {
                    passed = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Order with Id " + order.Id + " did not pass ruleset 1");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (passed) Console.WriteLine("Order with Id " + order.Id + " passed ruleset 1");
            passed = true;
            foreach (var rule in ruleset2) {
                if (!(rule.Invoke(order))) {
                    passed = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Order with Id " + order.Id + " did not pass ruleset 2");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (passed) Console.WriteLine("Order with Id " + order.Id + " passed ruleset 2");
        }
    }

    // Just a few orders for testing
    private static void AddOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 0, ClientName = "Joe", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed });
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 1, ClientName = "Mary", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed });
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 2, ClientName = "June", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed });
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 3, ClientName = "Joe", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Unconfirmed });
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 4, ClientName = "Lisa", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Unconfirmed });
    }

    // Rules in ruleset 1 checks if the user is called Joe and the order status is Confirmed
    private static void AddRules(List<Func<Order, bool>> ruleset1) {
        ruleset1.Add((order) => {
            return order.ClientName == "Joe";
        });
        ruleset1.Add((order) => {
            return order.Status == Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed;
        });
    }

    // Rules in ruleset 2 checks if the order status is Confirmed
    private static void AddRules2(List<Func<Order, bool>> ruleset2) {
        ruleset2.Add((order) => {
            return order.Status == Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed;
        });
    }

    public class Order {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }

        public enum OrderStatus { Confirmed, Unconfirmed }

    }
```

Other than that, you could also use LINQ, as suggested by [@itsme86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141432/itsme86):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        var orders = new List<Order>();

        AddOrders(orders);

        var confirmed = orders.Where(s => s.Status == Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed);

        foreach (var order in confirmed) {
            Console.WriteLine("Order with Id " + order.Id + " is confirmed");
        }
    }

    // Just a few orders for testing
    private static void AddOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 0, ClientName = "Joe", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed });
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 1, ClientName = "Mary", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed });
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 2, ClientName = "June", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Confirmed });
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 3, ClientName = "Joe", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Unconfirmed });
        orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 4, ClientName = "Lisa", Status = Order.OrderStatus.Unconfirmed });
    }

    public class Order {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }

        public enum OrderStatus { Confirmed, Unconfirmed }

    }
```